# Is there an API for Stack Overflow?

Tags: scripting, metadata, analysis, trend

**Executive Summary**

I want to track trending questions on SO myself.  Is there an API for accessing data on SO latest questions?  Or will I have to do screen-scraping?

**Boring Explanation**

Today I just thumbed through the latest questions, and said to myself "this is one way to gauge the interest level of technical topics" and "I could trawl this forum with a script and do some simple trend analysis myself".  Like a poor man's TIOBE.  An interesting and fun exercise.

Comment: Questions about SO itself belong on [meta].

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  When I looked at the meta tag, I was unsure of whether this q was truly "meta" or not :)  Yes, it's about SO, but no, it's not about something wrong or an enhancement per se... it's about writing a tool to use a thing out here on the Interwebs... so...

Comment: I did see a lot of nice posts about the downside of SO Scrapers tho'.